# Silverlight crashing in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, silverlight

I've used [this site](http://www.mp3ye.eu) before and had no problems. A few days ago Chrome starting acting up and I couldn't open Chrome at all. I unistalled / reinstalled it and now the site doesn't work for me anymore.

What could have caused this and what can I do to help fix it?

Chrome version: 23.0.1271.97 m (current)

Silverlight version: 5.1.10411.0 (also current)